# I want to using @WebServlet annotation and @Path annotation to same time in jetty

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey-2.0, servlet-3.0

First, Please forgive me for my clumsy English.

**[What I want to do]**

I want to know `@WebServlet` annotation by Servlet 3.0 and `@Path` annotation by Jersey 2.22.2, It is able to using same time?

**[That I want is to help]**

- Can I use two annotations at the same time?
- If I can use those annotations, is that way how to use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Path annotation defines a path to a [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) Web service so when you have **@Path("/SomeService")** it will translate into www.yourapp.com/baseRestUrl/SomeService. You can also define it on the methods which provides REST services. Note that baseRestUrl is defined inside web.xml or in class which extends Application class.

On the other hand **@WebServlet("/SomePath")** states that [Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) will be listening for request on the www.yourapp.com/SomePath, it is basically replacement of servlet-mapping element in web.xml. You can still configure servlets like this, it's up to you whether you prefer XML or annotation configuration.

Comment: > You can still configure servlets like this, it's up to you whether you prefer XML or annotation configuration.


It was also confirmed I. But I can't access **www.myapp.com/SomePath** with `@WebServlet` annotation.

Comment: No one can help with the info "can't access www.myapp.com/SomePath", What is the error message?, what about eclipse console/error logs?, please try to think in that way, you can upvote/accept this answer, if it helps.

Comment: It means url mapping failed, not able to locate the method inside @Webservlet annotated class. Refer https://www.google.ca/search?q=spring+url+mapping+404&rls=com.microsoft:en-CA:IE-Address&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7GGNI_enCA652&gfe_rd=cr&ei=jLUKWPCzCOGM8Qe7wZ7ACQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=%40webservlet+url+mapping+404

Comment: I can access to www.myapp.com/SomePath with `<servlet-mapping>`.
But I can't access to its with `@WebServlet("SomePath")`.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Please look at below source code if it is good if.
https://teratail.com/questions/52080

Comment: Try `@WebServlet("/SomePath")`

Comment: I've used the `@WebServlet("/SomePath")`.
But, it was not able to still access.